# Transitivity when only $aRb$ but not $bRc$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I was just wondering what happens with the transitivity in the following examples, sorry if its stupid I'm a newbie student :) .

$R = \{ (0,1) , (2,3) \} $
it is transitive right ? because there is $aRb$ but not $bRc$ so we can't find counter-example so its transitive by default.

and in this example :
$R = \{ (1,1) , (2,2) \}$
its symmetric , anti-symmetric and transitive right (because we can relate to $(1,1)$ as $aRb$ and $(1,1)$ as $aRc$ and then $(1,1)$ is $aRc$).

am I assuming wrongly or its correct?
Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially correct. A useful mechanical way to look at [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) of implications is to use the identity $[A\to B]\equiv [B\lor \neg A]$, so that, for instance, $$\forall a,\forall b,\forall c,((aRb\land bRc)\to aRc)$$

is the same as $$\forall a,\forall b,\forall c,(aRc\lor\neg (aRb)\lor \neg (bRc))$$